# Pass Data to Child Templates

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

How would I access data from a child template?

For example, her's my router:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource("users", function(){
        this.route('new');
    });
    this.resource("user", {path: '/users/:user_id'}, function(){
        this.route('edit');
    });
});
```

Route:

```
App.UsersIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return App.User.find();
    }
});
```

Single User Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user">
    <h2>{{name_full}} is the username on the resource template</h2>
    {{ outlet }}
</script>
```

Single User Index Template:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="user/index">
    <h2>{{name_full}} is the username on the index page.</h2>
    {{#linkTo users}}Back to All Users{{/linkTo}}
</script>
```

I understand how the single user template has access to a users object, but how can I give the sub route access?

I have visited the [Ember Router Guides](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/defining-your-routes/#toc_nested-resources), but this still isn't clear to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To give the sub-route access you need to define the UsersIndexRoute and return user from its model hook. So:

```
App.UserIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.modelFor("user");
  }
});
```

modelFor will lookup the current model for the specified route, which could be anything but in this case happens to be the parent.